# Docker: Unable to ping another host from inside of container running in swarm

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, ping, docker-swarm

**Environment:-**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
- image yogeshkathayat/node-ping which is a simple nodejs app running on a node-alpine build
- my current host IP: 10.255.8.21
- Ip that I want to ping: 10.255.8.53

**My compose file:-**

```
version: "3.3"
networks:
  basic:
services:
  ping-test:
    image: yogeshkathayat/node-ping
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - basic
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

**Issue:-**
I am not able to ping another host in the same local network from inside of the container,
if I remove ports section from my Compose file then it is working perfectly. but I want to expose the port to the outside world.

**Steps:-**

docker swarm init

docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml ping

docker exec -it /bin/bash //go inside the container

ping host in the same subnet or network

Comment: To debug get it working with `docker run` first then do the compose abstraction. Have you tried that?

Comment: What service are you running on the remote host such that it’s vital for it to receive ICMP packets?  This seems like an extremely artificial setup and describing your actual use case might be more useful.

Comment: yes using docker run and docker-compose up it is working perfectly. the issue is when I am running it on docker swarm.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes actually to make the actual setup easier to understand , I created this image. so the actual scenario is I am running 5 containers using docker swarm 1) backend container running node.js exposing 4001 port 2) frontend container running angular 3) cronjob container  4) postgres container 5) mongodb container exposing 27017 port ... and inside nodejs container i want to ping other hosts in local network.

Comment: I am able to ping google.com or any other public IP but not any IP that is in my local network. e.g. my host IP is 10.255.8.21, I am able to ping google.com but not able to ping 10.255.8.53 from inside of the container. using ping I want to show whether the host we have is up or down.